# How to reduce the vertical margin of tikzposter notes?

Tags: margins, tikzposter

By default there is a lot of space around tikzposter notes. Setting `innersep` will reduce horizontal and vertical margins on multi-line notes but on single-line notes the vertical margin is unaffected.

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\institute{Institute}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\block{Block}{Content}

\note[connection, radius=10cm, angle=0]{1a) one line}
\note[connection, radius=10cm, angle=300, innersep=0.5cm]{1b) one line}
\note[connection, radius=10cm, angle=240]{2a) one line\\another line}
\note[connection, radius=10cm, angle=180, innersep=0.5cm]{2b) one line\\another line}

\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I reduce the vertical margins in `1b)` ?

Comment: Please show us a compilable code ...

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1):

> The following answer only deals with the width of the notes.

All notes have a default width of `width=8cm`. If you want to decrease the horizontal size of the notes, you can specify the width explicitly:

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\institute{Institute}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\block{Block}{Content}

\note[connection, angle=0]{1a) one line}
\note[connection, angle=300, innersep=0.5cm, width=5cm]{1b) one line}
\note[connection, angle=240]{2a) one line\\another line}
\note[connection, angle=180, innersep=0.5cm]{2b) one line\\another line}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Find `tikzposter.sty` (I have mine in `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tikzposter`), find `max(\TP@noteheight,80pt)` and change it to `max(\TP@noteheight,20pt)` or some other value.

Comment: Hello to the site. Note that changing system files is a very bad idea! First, you may broke other things, second, any update might revert this. You should, at least, make a local copy of the file, but even that's a bad idea, because suddenly you have to files with the same name and completely different behavior. Good luck debugging it in the future.

Comment: Agreed. But I guess that it is difficult/impossible to change it in any other way since the note height is hard-coded in the tikzposter package.